# How to read data from a file in the App's bundle I macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, file, cocoa

I'm trying to read the data from a txt file on macOS. I use String(contentsOf:) and Bundle.main.path(forResource:) like I would on iOS. However, this doesn't work on macOS. I have tried several solutions from other posts but because of macOS they don't seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
My code:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "txt")! // no error
let url = URL(string: path)! // no error
let contents: String
do {
     contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
    print(error) // Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "The file couldn’t be opened because the specified URL type isn’t supported."
    contents = "ERROR"
}
print(contents)
```

I can save the data to a folder on disk, but I want to ship this file with my app.

Comment: Add your code to the question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URL(string` is the wrong API. It's only for URL strings starting with a scheme (`http://`, `file://`)

For file system **paths** you have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath`.

But in this situation there is a much better way

Replace

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "txt")!
let url = URL(string: path)! // no error
```

with

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "txt")
```